# Adding a '-' sign before any phone number based on a condition

Tags: bash, sed

I need to add a `-` sign before any phone number ending with `}` and remove that `}`

For example, consider this sample file:

```
*My phone number is 9999999999}<br>
Ram is calling to 88888888}<br>
653426} Rohan is trying to call 777777777*
```

Expected output:

```
*My phone number is -9999999999<br>
Ram is calling to -88888888<br>
-653426 Rohan is trying to call 777777777*
```

Comment: I've tried to format and edit the question for clarity, please review it... on this forum, you are expected to show what you have tried yourself to solve this problem and we'll try to identify and correct issues in your code.. so, please click [edit] and add your efforts.. see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources

Comment: ***Show Code***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
sed -i 's/\s\([0-9]*\)\}/ -\1/g' vv.txt
```

Description:

vv.txt is the file from the sample provided by you

`\s\([0-9]*\)\}` : will capture everything that is enclosed in a space and is a digit upto }

`-\1/g` : here we are replacing everything we captured in between space `\s` and symbol **}** in the previous step, with a negative sign

the output on the sample file is:

```
*My phone number is -9999999999<br>
Ram is calling to -88888888<br>
Rohan is trying to call 777777777*
```

To take care of the additional condition mentioned in comments you can do two things:

1.

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9]*\)\}/ -\1/g' vv.txt
```

but this will add a space in front of - if the line begins with the number as you said.

Alternatively if you don't want the space.

2.

```
sed -i 's/\s\([0-9]*\)\}/ -\1/g;s/^\([0-9]*\)\}/-\1/g' vv.txt
```

Comment: But it is not working, if the line starting with numbers. For example: 999999} is my number

Comment: @Abhishek_Upadhyay do edit your question to include the example I will modify it accordingly :)

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay do check the updated answer

Comment: Sure...I'll do that